# How to validate Envato Purchase Code in PHP

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

I'm working on Envato API to verify Purchase Code I used plugin sample code from GitHub https://github.com/codehaiku/Envato-Purchase-Code-Verifier here I added token and AUTHOR_SALES_ENDPOINT_URI = 'https://api.envato.com/v2/market/author/sale?code=' also when I used to try I'm getting error Invalid Purchase Code when to the valid purchase code. Did i missed anything here? Can anyone suggest me. Is there any other alternative way to do.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Envato Purchase Code Verifier</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <!-- // Include the EnvatoPurchaseCodeVerifier.php file that holds the verifier class.--> 
        <?php require_once 'EnvatoPurchaseCodeVerifier.php'; ?>
        <!-- // Create your own access token at (https://build.envato.com/create-token)-->
        <?php $access_token = 'my token here'; // Change 'your_token' value with your own token ?>
        <!-- // Create new instance of EnvatoPurchaseCodeVerifier. -->
        <!-- // Pass your own access token -->
        <?php $purchase = new EnvatoPurchaseCodeVerifier($access_token); ?>

        <?php $buyer_purchase_code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'purchase_code', FILTER_DEFAULT); ?>

        <!-- check if user submits the form -->
        <?php if ( ! empty( $buyer_purchase_code ) ) { ?>

            <?php $verified = $purchase->verified($buyer_purchase_code); ?>
            <!-- User purchase code is good!-->
            <?php if ( $verified ) { ?>
                <?php
                     $item_id = $verified->item->id; 
                     $item_name = $verified->item->name; 
                     $buyer = $verified->buyer; 
                     $license = $verified->license; 
                     $amount = $verified->amount; 
                     $sold_at = $verified->sold_at; 
                     $supported_until = $verified->supported_until;
                 ?>
                 <h1>Valid Purchase Code</h1>
                 <table>
                    <tr><td>Item ID:</td><td><?php echo $item_id; ?></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Item Name:</td><td><?php echo $item_name; ?></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Buyer:</td><td><?php echo $buyer; ?></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>License:</td><td><?php echo $license; ?></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Amount:</td><td><?php echo $amount; ?></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Sold At:</td><td><?php echo $sold_at; ?></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Supported Until:</td><td><?php echo $supported_until; ?></td></tr>
                </table>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <!-- Invalid purchase code -->
                <h1>Invalid Purchase Code</h1>
            <?php } ?>

        <?php } else  { ?>
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <label>Purchase Code: </label>
                <input type="text" name="purchase_code" placeholder="Type or paste the buyer's purchase code here"><br>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        <?php } ?>


    </div>
</body>
</html>


require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Curl\Curl;

final class EnvatoPurchaseCodeVerifier
{
    protected $accessToken = '';

    const AUTHOR_SALES_ENDPOINT_URI = 'https://api.envato.com/v2/market/author/sale?code=';

    /**
     * Class constructor, pass the access token.
     * @param mixed The access token <https://build.envato.com/create-token/>
     */
    public function __construct($accessToken)
    {
        $this->accessToken = $accessToken;
    }

    /**
     * Supply the purchase code of the buyer as argument.
     * @param  mixed $purchaseCode The purchase code of he buyer.
     * @return mixed (Boolean) False on fail, the api (Object) $curl->response info on success.
     */
    public function verified($purchaseCode)
    {
        if (empty($purchaseCode)) {
            return false;
        }

        $curl = new Curl();

        $curl->setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $this->accessToken);

        $curl->get(self::AUTHOR_SALES_ENDPOINT_URI, array(
            'code' => $purchaseCode
        ));

        $curl->close();

        if ($curl->error) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return $curl->response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds more like a question for the API maintainer. It's unlikely that someone with knowledge of this specific API is going to be able to help here.

Comment: @miken32 no actually I new with PHP so i unable to write the proper code that's the reason i use this plugin. Can you please visit this url and see https://build.envato.com/api/

Answer (score 1):

Please try following, Its tested and working

```
<?php 
$code = "86781236-23d0-4b3c-7dfa-c1c147e0dece";

// If you took $code from user input it's a good idea to trim it:

$code = trim($code);

// Make sure the code is valid before sending it to Envato:

if (!preg_match("/^(\w{8})-((\w{4})-){3}(\w{12})$/", $code))
    throw new Exception("Invalid code");

// Query using CURL:

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.envato.com/v3/market/author/sale?code={$code}",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 20,

    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Bearer KEY_HERE",
        "User-Agent: Enter a description of your app here for the API team"
    )
));
```

Answer (score -1):

Check whether you have updated the composer and ensure that you have the file EnvatoPurchaseCodeVerifier.php. Because seeing to your code snippet what I understand you try to add the class EnvatoPurchaseCodeVerifier in the same file and some php opening tag before that class is missing. The proper way would be put that in a different file and check whether the composer autoload works fine.

Comment: I just download this plugin and added my token and API key. Here I missed anything else any other alternative way?

Comment: Please see what kind of error message appear in the application ? Have you downloaded that github repository as a zip file ? You may be missed to update the composer. Use the command "composer update" in your command prompt to load the vendor libraries you need.

Comment: can you please guide me How should I update composer.

Comment: You can first install the composer and go to the project path in command prompt where composer.json file exist and type "composer update" there. You may be need to learn the basics of composer first : https://www.codementor.io/jadjoubran/php-tutorial-getting-started-with-composer-8sbn6fb6t

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
function verify_purchase_code($code) {
    $code = urlencode($code);
    $url = "https://envato.eduardofiorini.com/index.php?item=35215272&code=" . $code . "&domain=" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array('Content-type: application/json'));

    $ret = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if (!$ret) {
        $ret = file_get_contents($url);
    }

    $data = json_decode($ret??"{}",true);

    if($data["error"]){
        echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "message" => $data["msg"]));
        exit();
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```